# Registering date according to payment amount

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to register a date accoring to the amount a user is paying and the startdate.

I have 3 textboxes, `PaymentAmount`, `StartDay` (the day that user paid) and `EndDay` (when the payment expires).

If the PaymentAmount(decimal) is 1$, the StartDay is 01.01.2013 (the format is dd.mm.yyyy), then the EndDay should be 01.02.2013. If the PaymentAmount is 5$, the StarDay is 01.01.2013, then the EndDay should be 01.05.2013. But if the date is 01.09.2013 and PayemtAmount is 5$ then the EndDay should be 01.02.2014.

I didn't try anything yet, I mean ... is it possible to SUM somehow the PaymentAmount and the StartDay ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `DateTime.AddDays(double value)` (or AddMonths)?

Comment: You just want to add 1 month for each $1 of the payment amount? I think you want `DateTime.AddMonths`.

Comment: Thanks - the StackOverflow way to mark the question 'solved' is to write your own answer below (or prompt Jim or Artemix to do it!) and then accept it as soon as you're able to (20 minutes?).

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't got to worry about decimal values this should work:

```
        int paymentAmmount = (int)Math.Floor(5.24);

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;

        DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(paymentAmmount);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add 1 month per each $ of payment, then this will do the work:

```
string textboxvalue = textBox1.Text; // put textbox value here
decimal decAmount;
if (decimal.TryParse(textboxvalue, out decAmount)
{
    int amount = (int)Math.Floor(decAmount);
    DateTime transactionDate = DateTime.Today;

    DateTime expiryDate = transactionDate.AddMonths(amount);
}
```